# clipPath is not working if I use <path> inside clipPath , but it works for <circle>

Tags: html, svg, clip-path

I am trying to create a clipPath image using svg. I am trying to do it with native clipPath method of SVG.

> My problem is that if I use a path inside  the
>   image won't be show. But if I use a circle instead of path, It
>   displays wihtout any problem.

My code goes here,

```html
<svg width="660" height="495" style="background: #333">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="ellipsePath">
      <path d="M0.785,0.075C0.52-0.031,0.337-0.022,0.141,0.185s-0.187,0.534,0.02,0.73s0.48-0.023,0.676-0.23
        C1.034,0.478,1.092,0.198,0.785,0.075z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image width="660" height="495" y="-100" xlink:href="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" clip-path="url(#ellipsePath)"/>
</svg>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nt4dfLbz/)

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Your path is so small, no wonder you don't see anything. [Here it's just been scaled x100](https://jsfiddle.net/junea4m8/). VTCing as typo won't help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for your support,
adding **clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"** to the **clipPath** solved my issue.

```
<svg width="256" height="248" style="background: #333">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="ellipsePath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0.785,0.075C0.52-0.031,0.337-0.022,0.141,0.185s-0.187,0.534,0.02,0.73s0.48-0.023,0.676-0.23
                    C1.034,0.478,1.092,0.198,0.785,0.075z"></path>

    </clipPath>
</defs>
<image width="100%" height="100%"  xlink:href="https://placeimg.com/256/248/any" clip-path="url(#ellipsePath)"/>
```

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrqgw3Lb/)